# Get the third Regex between special char

Tags: regex, vb.net, text

I have this text:

```
2|@Favo|Name||26.0000|50.10000|_GRE|||||City|Road||||
```

I want to capture anything between those special chars: `||`

For example, I want to capture "Name" only or I want to capture "City"
I've spent many hours and all I came up with is this regex:

```
([^|].*[$|])\w+
```

Here are the required values:
[image: Values]
How can I capture one of them?

Thank you.

Comment: It is not clear what the requirements are, could you clarify them please? You might always split the string with `'|'` and then look for any item that meets your criteria.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I want to get the values between "|value|", from the text

Comment: That does not help, there is no `|value|` text in your input string.

Comment: `\d+\|@\w+\|(\w+)`... then use group `$1`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I've updated the main question will you check it plz?

Comment: @l'L'l it didn't worked, it just captures that first two since it start capturing from "@"

Comment: What about a blacklisting approach to extract non-empty and non-digit items after a split with `|`?

Comment: You aren't using the capture group... if you don't want to use the capture group then do the opposite: `(\d+\|@\w+\|)\w+`... Also it's unclear what your question is, since the title says "Get the third"... this implies you want `Name` only.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I don't know the blacklisting approach, can you explain it please?

Comment: Well, I just tried using C# - see https://ideone.com/GuAnTF. It can be easily converted to VB.NET.

Comment: @l'L'l yeah for example I want the third value, or fourth, n other words I want the value between those | |

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You are the best man, it worked. thanks

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Can you post the answer so I can mark it as an answer

Comment: But it  is in C#, let me re-write in VB.NET.

Comment: This pattern should work to get everything starting after "2" ... `([^|\d]+|[\d]+\.[\d]+)`, if you want that also use: `([^|]+)`

Comment: @I'L'I your method also working, thanks man.but it captures the first one how can I make capture the second one for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may split the string with `|` removing empty entries and also all those that are blank or consisting only of digits:

```
Dim strng As String = "2|@Favo|Name||26.0000|50.10000|_GRE|||||City|Road||||"
Dim reslt As List(Of String) = strng.Split(New String() {"|"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Where(
    Function(m) m.All(AddressOf Char.IsDigit) = False And String.Equals(m.Trim(), String.Empty) = False).ToList()
Console.Write(String.Join(", ", reslt))
```

Output:

[image]